# Trying to Run Jupyter Notebook from Git-Bash But Getting 'zmq.h' No File or Directory Error

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda and with it install Git Bash to run commands through bash. After installing Anaconda and adding the directories to the PATH variable, I was not able to run Jupyter notebook of Git Bash. It provides the following error.

```
 jupyter notebook
_cffi_ext.c
anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Falle\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
```

After I received the Error I checked the version on Jupyter to see if something is off. And the following is what I received

```
$ jupyter --version
_cffi_ext.c
anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
_cffi_ext.c
anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
_cffi_ext.c
anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
_cffi_ext.c
anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : not installed
jupyter client   : not installed
jupyter lab      : 2.2.6
nbconvert        : not installed
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

I tried installing the following packages but it states all requested packages are already installed (used conda install not pip)

I posted the picture of the list of my PATH variable.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems something must have corrupted the `jupyter` environment.
For me, it worked after re-installing it with:

```sh
pip install jupyter
```